# How to send synthesized MotionEvent through the system?

Tags: android, events

I know how to "synthesize" a MotionEvent:

```
  event = MotionEvent.obtain(downTime, eventTime, MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN, x, y, 0);
```

What I am stuck at is how to "send/post/fire/distribute" it through the system, so that it is handled "as if" a real user actually touched the screen with his or her finger.

Is this possible at all?

If so, how do I accomplish this?

Comment: Can you paste your layout and part of code where are you using that? pls...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, it's prevented by design.  The concern is that such a feature can be used to subvert the entire security model - e.g. by "injecting" touches to contact the marketplace, arrange an install, accept the security warnings .. all on its own.

This has been discussed at some length [here](http://groups.google.com/group/android-platform/browse_thread/thread/77a2add4384202dc?pli=1) and following.

If this answers your question, kindly click the checkmark to the left - thanks!

Comment: If your answer turns out to be correct, then I don't like it. :) What you're saying makes sense but if you are familiar with the InstrumentationTestCase class I think it does what I am trying to accomplish. Are you totally sure about this? Is it possible to at least "fake" MotionEvents to **my** own app/activity/view only?

Comment: @REG If you turn out to be the one who is right, I'll like it :)  The availability of InstrumentationTestCase, Monkey, etc indeed demonstrate the capacity for "add-on" event injectors. What I read  (sorry, don't recall ref as this was months back) is that events come into the system through a hardware secured gate.  If you have the key, you can inject events.  The tools are apparently making use of special keys for use in highly restricted conditions.  I look forward to hearing of anything else you may find...

Comment: I already gave you a +1 for the only clue so far I got about this challenge. I will give shortly another +1 for further clarifying this issue in your comment. As I said in my comment, I am not really interested in injecting an event into the **system**, I am only interested in accomplishing a text-selection task in one of **my** views. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5250290/why-doesnt-this-motionevent-simulation-work Is this possible at all?

Comment: for lack of an acceptable answer to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5250290/why-doesnt-this-motionevent-simulation-work I concede defeat and accept your answer. :(

Answer (score 19):

What you are trying to do is perfectly possible and simple:

```
void simulateEventDown( View v, long x, long y )
{
    MotionEvent e = MotionEvent.obtain( SystemClock.uptimeMillis(),
                                        SystemClock.uptimeMillis(), 
                                        MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN, 
                                        x, y, 0);
    v.dispatchTouchEvent(e);
}
```

Comment: Thank you!  This is exactly what I needed to get the right soft keyboard to open up in a WebView. I have to simulate a click into the input box.

Comment: @pryma all actions except ACION_MOVE are dispatching without proplem. when setting action to ACTION_MOVE it is always throwing arrayindexoutofboundsexception at MotionEvent.getX(). Do you have any idea what might be going on?

Comment: Looks like if `v` is a `ViewGroup` it won't dispatch event any further than it's `ViewGroup` object itself (in other words, it's equal to call `dispatchTouchEvent` and `onTouchEvent`).

Comment: calling `v.onTouchEvent(e)` instead of `v.dispatchTouchEvent(e)` resulted in different behaviors for me