# Why doesn't this MotionEvent simulation work?

Tags: android, events, touch, textselection

In one of the views in an exercise app, am trying to perform text selection programmatically.

I am able to (programmatically) enter "text selection mode", which is visually indicated by CursorControllers (AKA handles) on the top-left corner of the view.

If I **manually** drag the right CursorController, then click it again (in the emulator), it works as expected (perfectly), showing a brief message: "Text copied to clipboard".

But when I try to programmatically drag that right CursorController, nothing happens.

The way I try to do this is by simulating a MotionEvent. In the view, I call:

```
  event = MotionEvent.obtain(downTime, eventTime, MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN, x, y, 0);
  MainActivity.onTouch(this, event);
```

In the MainActivity I of course implement OnTouchListener:

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) { // called BEFORE button's onTouchEvent()
    Log.v("MainActivity::onTouch()", describeEvent(v, event));
    switch (event.getAction()) { 
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN: 
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP: 
            if (!v.hasFocus()) { 
                v.requestFocus(); 
             } 
             break; 
    } 
    return false; 
}
```

If I understand correctly, by mere returning 'false' from onTouch, **Android keeps looking for another UI object to consume the MotionEvent object, eventually reaching my view**.

Why doesn't this happen?

I must be missing something very fundamental...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For lack of a working solution, I can only conclude that what I have been trying to accomplish isn't possible on the Android, for reasons of security. An explanation can be found in the following link: [How to send synthesized MotionEvent through the system?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240287/how-to-send-synthesized-motionevent-through-the-system/5240821#5240821)

Answer (score 0):

The `OnTouchListener` is called inside the View from `dispatchTouchEvent` which in turn has been called from `ViewGroup` or a `TouchDelegate`. If you call the listener from your view it simply does what ever you have there and then returns. It doesn't magically delegate the touch event anywhere.

Instead Call `dispatchTouchEvent()` on your view to get the correct result.

For unit testing your application behavior on text selection etc. See http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/testing/activity_test.html

Comment: Kudos for being the 1st to try answering this difficult question. Unfortunately however, dispatchTouchEvent() doesn't produce the much yearned for events. Perhaps @DJC was right in his answer to the following question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240287/how-to-send-synthesized-motionevent-through-the-system