# Perform motion event on scroll view Android

Tags: android, tcp, scroll, motion

Im creating client/server app and I want to send motion event performed on scroll view on client side to server side, and perform it on the same scroll view.

I have no problems sending motion event over TCP connection, but having problem performing that motion event on same scroll view on server side.

How do I programmatically  perform motion event on scroll view? Help.

Answer (score 1):

Use the method `public void scrollTo(int x, int y)` on the `ScrollView` .

Comment: That is not what I need... There is a big difference between performing motion on scrollView and performing .scrollBy on the same...

Comment: my bad, you were looking for the motion event? The thing is you cannot do this since it is part of a security feature in android as mentioned in this [post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5240287/how-to-send-synthesized-motionevent-through-the-system/5240821#5240821). Hope it helps!

Comment: But I don`t want to perform system event...
ScrollView a = (ScrollView)findViewById.....
MotionEvent motion = MotionEvent.obtain(....
a.performMotionEvent(motion)

Problem is that there is no method performMotionEvent. :(
I think for this, there are no security problems... Right?

Comment: there shouldn't have been, since you can do a click on a view programmatically. Guess you ll have to find an another way around..